# Which Spotify API gives access to the complete audio data?

Tags: python, spotify, libspotify

I would like to save a Spotify track as MP3 file. Is there an API available (preferably with Python bindings) which gives access to the complete audio data from songs? Preferably compressed data, but uncompressed is also fine. Note: this is for personal use only, I'm not distributing my application.

I already found this: [The audio is delivered through a push-callback called by libspotify when data is available](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.51/structsp__session__callbacks.html#a33a31478b8de1882ad7847ad033fbaeb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Python library seems to give access to uncompressed audio data:
[pyspotify - Playing music](http://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/quickstart/#playing-music)

Answer (score 2):

None of them. The [Spotify Developer Terms of Service](https://developer.spotify.com/developer-terms-of-use/) explicitly forbid the development of applications that save audio content:

> §IV.3.f. **No Content Saving Functionality.** Your SDA shall not provide any functionality that would enable users to download or save Spotify Content. For example, your SDA shall not allow users to “rip” any songs or download cover art.

Answer (score 1):

Using libspotify you are responsible to route the data to the audio subsystem. No one can stop you to do other things with the data. But its correct that its not allowed to save this data to the disk.